# Webpack-dev-server on laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, homestead

I am developing a Laravel-Vue app using Laravel/Homestead. The Vue code is compiled using laravel-mix, all using fresh installs (it's a new project).

I would like to be able to test my Vue components 'outside' of the Laravel project. So I figured I just

1) Add a script in package.json like this

`"devser": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",`

2) Add an entry point main.js file in which I can run my components isolated

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Example from './components/Example.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(Example)
})
```

3) add a webpack.config.js file to configure webpack for this isolated app. I just took it from the vuejs template: webpack-simple and changed the entry point path.

So far, running the devser script does compile the code without errors, and apparently, the code is served at (webpack output)

```
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /dist/
404s will fallback to /index.html
```

However, opening localhost:8080 gives an error: This site can't be reached, localhost refuses to connect. So I have been searching for a while and found things about devserver proxy's and stuff like that but I don't understand what I would need to add to my webpack.config.js.

Maybe good to note: I am not interested here in calling the Laravel backend from these Vue components, it is just for testing the components in an isolated way. My next step was to add Vue-storybook to the party to do this.

To summarize, I am looking for one codebase (Laravel + Vue on Homestead) where I can separately test the components. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: If I am not logged in to the vagrant machine, I can navigate to the project folder and run

`npm run devser`

which serves the project at localhost:8080 and this URL does work. So I have a workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running `webpack-dev-server` inside your Homestead box. If so, you need to forward port 8080 from your host to the Vagrant box:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#forwarding-additional-ports

Add this to your `Homestead.yaml`:

```yaml
ports:
    - send: 8080
      to: 8080
```

Then, run `vagrant reload --provision` to apply the changes.

Now you should be able to view http://localhost:8080/